# How to detect / avoid overlapping of text in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am having `QGraphicsView`, which has multiple `QGraphicsItem`'s. On `QGraphicsView` I am performing multiple transformation like `zoom-in`, `zoom-out`, `Fit-in` etc.
In QGraphicsItem, I am having few rectangles and some polylines. Polylines are attached to rectangles. The positions of polylines are very near to each other. Every polyline has its own name written above it. So when the design loads, names of the polylines `overlap` with each other. If I zoomed-in till particular level the distance between polylines makes their names `non overlapping`.

> So I want to detect overlapping of text. If text overlap, I should not
> show them on polyline. Once I zoomed in, and when text become `non overlapping`, names of polylines should be visible.

I thought like this.
After every `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` I am calculating for intersection.

```
void myClass :: addItems() 
 {
       QGraphicsTextItem *text1 = new QGraphicsTextItem("line1");
       text1->setPos(20,40);                 
       text1->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::black);
       scene->addItem(text1);
 }
    
void myClass::ZoomIn()
 {
      double scaleFactor = 1.1;
      view->scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
      Intersection();
 }

 void myClass:: Intersection()
 {
      QList<QGraphicsTextItem*> textList;
      _isIntersect = false;
      foreach(QGraphicsItem* currentItem, _scene->items())
      {
          QGraphicsTextItem* tItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsTextItem*>(currentItem);
          if(tItem)
          {
              textList.push_back(tItem);
          }
      }
      for(int i = 0 ; i < textList.size(); i++)
      {
           QGraphicsTextItem* iItem = textList[i];
           for( int j = i+1; j < textList.size(); j++)
           {
              QGraphicsTextItem* jItem = textList[j];
              if(iItem->boundingRect().intersects(jItem->boundingRect()))
              {
                  _isIntersect = true;
                  break;
              }
            }
            if(_isIntersect)
               break;
        }
    
        if(!_isIntersect)
            qDebug()<<"Not intersected ";
        else
            qDebug()<<"Intersected ";
}
```

But for every view, above logic is showing "Intersected". Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Each QGraphicsItem has a `boundingRect()` method; if your text is represented by separate `QGraphicsTextItem` objects, you could call `intersects()` on the various `QGraphicsTextItem` objects to see if they intersect, and if they do, don't show them.  (Note that doing this the naive way and checking every `QGraphicsTextItem` against every other `QGraphicsTextItem` is O(N^2) and will get slow if there are a lot of them; if that's a problem you could use a quad-tree or some other indexing/caching mechanism to make it more efficient)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I tried what you were saying but for every `view` it is showing `intersected` irrespective of multiple `zoom-in`.  Am I right in logic ? I have updated the code in question.